# WPF Chart with data plotting on both x (datetime range) and y axis

Tags: wpf, toolkit

In the Chart control of WPF Toolkit , how can i add plot data on both x and y axis . The graph has numerical data plotted on y axis and a timeline on x axis . To better understand this refer below image. As seen from the image, data is plotted both against x and y axis (i.e after the first negative value in red , data has been plotted against the timeline of x axis and stretches across the timeline). So in this case , i would need to plot 2 values on the x axis - 1) the start time and 2) the end time for a single column ie its a datetime range also on the y axis i would be plotting it against values and as the scale suggests , it is numerical.

[image: Requirement]

Can this be replicated using the chart control in WPF toolkit  or is there any workarounds/third party WPF controls which can attain this?.

Comment: What is the purpose of blue rectangles above the x-axis? As of red lines near the first column, they can be added if to change the source code of the wpf toolkit. Or maybe it isn't necessary and can be changed inside DataPointStyle. I'll try later.

Comment: Each colour represents a selected parameter and shows if it is available or lacking in the graphs based on positive or negative values. So in  this case lets say blue represents parameter A red represents Parameter B and I have about 8 such parameters which will be displayed alongside these on selection (from checkboxes)

Comment: I still hasn't understood how these blue columns are drawn. The 'parameters' concept makes it even more confusing, because I can't imagine 8 parameters with 8 different colors and coulmns. It would be better to have an example of input data.

Comment: sorry for the latereply vortex. thanks for your response. i just identified that my req cannot be met using wpf tollkit so am doing it the old fashioned way : wpf graphics

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved if you shape your data accordingly. For example if you have your data points like

```
Time               Value
09:51               -4      
09:52               -2
09:53               -2
09:54               -2
..
..
..
10:11               -4
```

you will be able to plot a red rectangle with a long bar at 09:51 AM (Start Time) and long bar at 10:11 AM (End Time).